# Why does Apache HTTP mod_proxy perform unpredictably in Docker Swarm?

Tags: apache, docker, docker-swarm, mod-proxy

I have a fairly simple Docker implementation that consists of two containers running on an overlay network:  one running Apache HTTP 2.4.16 and another running a Spring Boot app (using Tomcat 8).  The Apache container handles all external https requests and proxies traffic (via mod_proxy_http) to the Spring Boot app running in the second container.  My proxy configs look like this:

```
ProxyPass /web-portal http://web-portal:8080/web-portal 
retry=0 
ProxyPassReverse /web-portal http://web-portal:8080/web- 
portal
ProxyTimeout 300
```

I'm setting the Spring Boot/Tomcat `server.connection-timeout` to the same value as Apache's `ProxyTimeout`

This all works just fine when running in Docker; however, I'm wanting to move to Docker Swarm and that's when I run into issues.  I've set up a very simple Docker swarm environment with a single node that also serves as the manager (by running `docker swarm init`).  I am running the same exact containers that I describe above.  Initially, behavior is as expected: Apache proxies https traffic destined to `/web-portal` to the Spring Boot app.  After a period of time (that is seemingly unpredictable) the proxy stops working and I see entries like this in the Apache `ssl_error.log` file:

```
[proxy_http:error] [pid 222] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: 
[client 10.255.0.2:64842] AH01102: error reading status line from 
remote server web-portal:8080, referer: 
https://ojbc.org/web-portal/

[proxy:error] [pid 222] [client 
10.255.0.2:64842] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by 
/web-portal/activity, referer: https://ojbc.org/web- 
portal/
```

When this happens, the only solutions I've found are to `docker rm -f` the Apache HTTP container and create a new container (`docker run`) or just wait for some period of time and the proxy starts working again.

To eliminate variables, I removed Spring Boot from the equation and just ran plain ol' Tomcat8 in the second container, but the issues were still present.  I've also tried proxying via `mod_proxy_ajp` rather than `mod_proxy_http` -- but I get similar errors.

I have never seen these problems when running these containers in normal (non-Swarm) Docker mode.  I've scoured this site, and others, trying to better understand why introducing Docker Swarm would cause these issues and what the solution might be, but I'm at a loss.  I'm guessing it might have something to do with load balancing in Docker Swarm, but I don't have much to back up that theory.  I appreciate any thoughts you may have. Please let me know if I can provide any further detail about my environment.